# Merge Sort -- Optimization by Cache Line Size?

Tags: arrays, sorting, caching, mergesort, insertion-sort

One of my friends recently mentioned that you can reduce the real run-time of merge sort by "cutting it short". Instead of breaking up the array all the way down to individual blocks, he mentioned that you should stop at the point where the individual array sizes are equal to the size of the cache line, as the entire array will then be loaded into cache. At this point, you should use an alternative sort (i.e. insertion sort) to merge each of the arrays, and then finish your merge sort.

While the BigO suggests otherwise, he suggestion seems to make intuitive sense. Can someone confirm or deny this, and/or provide any more information about how and why this works?

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

The combination of insertion sort to create small runs, then switching to merge sort is called timsort. Wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Answer (score 0):

Well, the (somewhat abstract) answer is that Big-O only is useful for large numbers: it throws away constant factors: O(n)=O(3n), it throws away lower-order terms: O(n²+3n)=O(n²). So yes, you can't tell from the Big-O notation.

Also, the Big-O notation is usually used on a very simple model where each "operation" just costs 1, and it doesn't know about caches.

So that's why the model doesn't tell you this could be useful. I guess you could look at Donald E. Knuth's "Sorting and Searching", where he does runtime analysis down to lower terms (but still doesn't account for cache, IIRC) on a fictional assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing complexity using *O* (*Ω*, *Θ*, etc...) is only meant to describe how an algorithm performs as the input size grows.  If you look at the actual function, you can see that the constant factors become less important as the input grows.  Overall, input size dominates the function.

In practice the constant factors do matter though (cache misses, instruction latency, etc...), which is why [RadixSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) is generally rarely used.  For example, reading from a register takes about 1/5 the time reading from the lowest level in cache (that's about 1/5 the time of the next level, etc...).  Since they're orders of magnitude, in practice cache costs often dominate the real performance of an algorithm.

Insertion sort does use the cache fairly efficiently, generally as long as the data fits into cache.  Since it's sequential, it also interacts well with the predictor.  Both are often reasons why it is better for smaller inputs.  Another good example is [QuickSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), which is technically `O(n^2)`, but still used in practice a lot because it has better cache characteristics.  [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (Python's and Java's default) also uses insertion sort for smaller inputs.

Comment: On my system, Intel 2600K 3.4 ghz, the time to sort 4,194,304 64 bit unsigned integers of psuedo random data: radix sort - 203 ms ; merge sort - 297 ms ; microsoft std::sort - 344 ms ; microsoft std::stable_sort - 375 ms . The std::sort is [intro sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort). The std::stable_sort is a bottom up merge sort that uses a temp array 1/2 the size of the original array, doing some extra copies and a final merge step.

Comment: Counting-sort using a bitmap is able to sort on my laptop (x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz) in 250ms, even with the compiler generating broken code (314ms for `std::sort`).  It has a higher memory overhead than intro-sort, but it's psuedo-branchless like radix-sort (1/4 branch misses)  so it still averages a higher instruction throughput (2/cycle vs. 1.9/cycle).  I'm not sure why merge-sort is outperforming it though.  I think spread-sort has also been shown to outperform intro-sort in certain scenarios.